# How to make the grid in a fixed size even when the values changed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, css-grid

I am creating etch-a-sketch. Currently, i figured out how to create a grid width user input values. But when the values changes the grid size changes.  I want to make the width of the grid stays same whenever cell value changes. What should i do for that. I tried adjusting grid template rows and columns. It didn't work

Thank you

Here's my code

```
.grid{
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-grid;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    gap: 1px;
}

.button-div{
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');



//div for buttons
const buttonDiv = document.createElement('div');
buttonDiv.classList.add('button-div');
container.appendChild(buttonDiv);

//A button to reset Everything
const resetButton = document.createElement('button');
resetButton.textContent = 'Reset';
buttonDiv.appendChild(resetButton);

//grid in a seperate div
const grid = document.createElement('div');
grid.classList.add('grid');
container.appendChild(grid);

//function to create grid
function makeGrid(value){
    let gridWidth = 200 / value;
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${value}, ${gridWidth}px)`;
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${value}, ${gridWidth}px)`;
    for(let i = 0; i < value; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < value; j++){
        const cell = document.createElement('div');
        cell.classList.add('cell');
        cell.addEventListener('mouseover', toBlack);
        grid.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
}


//to change the cell color to black on mouseover
function toBlack(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

function resetGrid(){
    const value = prompt('Input a number of Squares');
    grid.innerHTML = '';
    makeGrid(value);
}

resetButton.addEventListener('click',resetGrid);

window.onload = () => {makeGrid(16)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy + pasted the code in your question to create a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k8ebmqd4/

What you've created so far is a fixed size `.grid`, where the number and size of the inner `div.cell` vary depending on the user input.
Understanding your  question correctly, this is not what you want. The `div.cell` should always stay 12.5x12.5 (that's what I see onload of the fiddle).
If that's the case, just change this line:
`let gridWidth = 200 / value;`
to:
`let gridWidth = 12.5;`
And now the `.grid` sizes depending on the number of cells in it.

Solution in according to comments below: remove the `gap` style from `.grid` and add a border to `.cell`: `.cell{border:1px solid #FFFFFF;}`. Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/t5akxof2/

Comment: I think i might have asked the wrong question. I want to make the width of the grid stays same whenever i cell value changes. What should i do for that.

Comment: @ancxanas what do you define as 'the grid' then? The `#container` or a `.cell` ? Your code already preserves the width of `#container`. My adjustment preserves the width of `.cell`.

Comment: I am talking about `.grid`. it changes size when the cell numbers increase or decrease. i want it to stay same at 1 and 16 or more.

Comment: @ancxanas okay, I see now what you mean I think. With larger number of cells, the '200px' is not always dividable without rounding issues. If you leave out the gap on the .grid and replace it with a border on the cells, the `.grid` always stays the same size. Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/t5akxof2/

Comment: @ancxanas okay I've added it to my answer, if it really solved your question, please accept the answer itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cloud use this:

```css
// Container for columns
.h-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

// Container for rows
.w-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-needed {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.container-rest {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="w-container">

  <div class="container-needed"> </div>

  <div class=container-rest> </div>

</div>
```

with this, the first elements takes as much as it needs and the second the rest, you could add more then two if you want...
the container could be a fixed size